# Browser concurrent threads

Tags: multithreading, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, google-chrome

I've been looking around for information on the threading model / count common browsers use.

Specifically I imagine when a browser visits a page it will kick off new threads to download the linked resources (css / images etc.) it needs to render the page. I assume there is a finite limit to the amount of concurrent threads they will use, this would conserve bandwidth for the resources nearer the top of the page so the "above the fold" stuff will render quickly.

Does any one have any information on the size of he thread pools used in specific modern browsers? Also if I've oversimplified their operation please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous downloads do not require separate threads; they're handled by the operating system.

However, browsers do have an upper bound (usually 2, 6, 8, or 15) on the number connections to each domain name.  ([Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections-per-server)) [(IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282402))

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer and the links. The Firefox Network.http.max-connections-per-server property sounds like what I'm talking about, it seems firefox three will use 15 concurrent downloads. Not so sure about the IE link through, it seems to be referring specifically to file downloads (not stuff needed to render the page). But as a ballpark 15 works for me.

Comment: @Jonathan: The IE article is referring to both.  A CSS file is also a file download; it just ends up at a different place.

Comment: Fair enough, I wondered while reading it, their language is just a little clumsy. Thanks Again!

Comment: @Jonathan To be specific, Firefox uses one background thread that polls all network connections simultaneously, plus I believe there is another thread that does DNS lookups, and another thread that does SSL handshakes.