# Is Chrome multithreaded in Loading static files?

Tags: multithreading, google-chrome, browser

How google chrome handling the static files (js/css/images), is it using 2 different threads for web and static files?
If it is. are Firefox/Opera/Safari the same?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser concurrent threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264440/browser-concurrent-threads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers will load multiple files simultaneously using asynchronous connections without threads.

However, browsers do have an upper bound (usually 2, 6, 8, or 15) on the number connections to each domain name.  ([Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections-per-server)) [(IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282402))